# Append slice of pointer into another slice of pointer Go

Tags: go, pointers, slice

Suppose I have this struct

```
type Rectangle struct {
    height string
    width  string
}
```

And I have a test variable that exactly looks like this

```
testvar := []*Rectangle{
    {
        height: "100",
        width:  "100",
    },
    {
        height: "200",
        width:  "200",
    },
}
```

What I'm trying to do here is to append this test variable into another []*Rectangle with this looping

```
anothervar:= []*Rectangle{}
for _, ptr := range testvar {
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", ptr)
    anothervar = append(anothervar, ptr)
    fmt.Printf("%p %v \n", anothervar, anothervar)
    fmt.Println()
}
```

At the end, I got this [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fduGD.png)

What I wanted to print is anothervar address and value

Comment: Try to set the ptr to a local variable like: `ptr := ptr` inside the for loop

Comment: doesn't work, I wanted to print its addresses and value

Comment: Another idea is: a) use spew.Dump (requires external lib) or b) define a `String() string` method in your type

Comment: doesnt fix the problem sir

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/d-nBrOKUB4p

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is what you want. But following link of playground code allow you print the content of array of struct pointer by using non-built-in library.

https://go.dev/play/p/tcfJYb0NnVf

You may want to refer to the library to know how to print content or just use the library itself.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your slice is a slice of pointer to rectangle, so when it is printed out, it is printing out the values, but those values are pointers.

You could try something like this to print out the values:

```
import (
    "fmt"
)

type Rectangle struct {
    height string
    width  string
}

func main() {
    
    testvar := []*Rectangle{
        {
            height: "100",
            width:  "100",
        },
        {
            height: "200",
            width:  "200",
        },
    }

    anothervar:= []*Rectangle{}
    for _, ptr := range testvar {
        fmt.Printf("%v\n", ptr)
        anothervar = append(anothervar, ptr)
        fmt.Printf("%p %+v \n", anothervar, anothervar)
        fmt.Println()
        printRectSlice(anothervar)
    }
}

func printRectSlice(s []*Rectangle) {
    fmt.Printf("{")
    for _, r := range s {
        fmt.Printf("%v", *r)
    }
    fmt.Println("}")
}
```